# Does an eigenstate of angular momentum necessarily have a certain inversion-parity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory

The inversion eigenvalue of an angular momentum eigenstate $|\ell,m\rangle$ is fixed by its $\ell$

$\langle r | \ell,m\rangle = Y^\ell_m(r) \rightarrow Y^\ell_m(-r) = (-1)^\ell  Y^\ell_m(r)$

I'm wondering how to reconcile this with the fact that two odd-$\ell$ states can add up to an odd-$\ell$ state as in

$|\ell,m\rangle =\sum_{m_1,m_2} |\ell_1,m_1\rangle |\ell_2,m_2\rangle \langle \ell_2,m_2|\langle \ell_1,m_1| \ell,m\rangle$

The inversion eigenvalue of the left hand  side is $(-1)^\ell$ but the right hand side is a sum of states with inversion eigenvalue $(-1)^{\ell_1+\ell_2}$ multiplied by some scalars(Clebsch-Gordan coefficients). But the coefficients can be non-zero even if $\ell$ and $\ell_1+\ell_2$ have different inversion eigenvalues, the only condition being that $|\ell_1-\ell_2|\le \ell \le \ell_1+\ell_2$.

What am I missing? Does this mean that a state of definite angular momentum $|\ell,m\rangle$ (with odd $\ell$) can be inversion-odd or inversion-even depending on whether it is a single-particle state or it is a composite of two inversion-odd single-particle states?

Comment: so where's the problem?  $(-1)^\ell \times (-1)^{\ell_1+\ell_2}$ doesn't need to be $1$; it could be $(-1)$.

Comment: the inversion parity of the LHS :$(-1)^\ell$ should be the same as the inversion parity of the terms on the RHS : $(-1)^{\ell_1+\ell_2}$, right?

Comment: right… I see it now.  I was likely in caffeine deficit when I commented.

Comment: I suspect you are "scoping" your Clebsch-decomposition equation improperly, by fudging the implicit tensor product on the r.h.side. For ℓ =1, the l.h.side is parity odd, but so is the r.h.side, which is *not* a product of 2 spherical harmonics you appear to imagine! $\langle r|\ell_1,m_1;\ell_2,m_2\rangle $ also has odd parity for spin 1, but you must consider what angular momentum operators do in their coproduct, linear in P-odd angular momenta, *not* bilinear!!

Comment: ...after all,  the r.h.side  is really a 3-vector, so P-odd.

Comment: Thanks, @CosmasZachos. I guess I never thought very hard on what $\langle r|\ell_1,m_1;\ell_2,m_2\rangle$ means. In my mind, I thought of it as interchangeable with $\langle r|\ell_1,m_1\rangle \langle r|\ell_2,m_2\rangle$. You're saying this isn't true. How then would you represent the wavefunction of the state $|\ell_1,m_1;\ell_2,m_2\rangle$ and see that it is inversion-odd? In what basis are you seeing the RHS as a 3-vector. I was thinking in terms of spinless states with real-space angular momentum, hence the spherical harmonics all over the place.

Comment: You note you effectively wrote $\langle r| \otimes \langle r|$ on the right; I guess I can think of the antisymmetric tensor product of two 3-vectors as a cross-product of sorts. Do you want an example?

Comment: I do note that. I guess that forces me to clarify what I mean by the states and their wavefunctions. Here, I'm thinking of actual physical states of a boson or fermion, so $|1,m_1;1,m_2\rangle$ means for me, a state with two spinless fermions or bosons each of which transform like a p-orbital. Its wavefunction $\langle r_1 | \otimes \langle r_2 | 1,m_1;1,m_2\rangle$ is a bilinear of spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell_1,m_1}(r_1) Y_{\ell_2,m_2}(r_2)$ appropriately (anti-)symmetrized. This state transforms like a single boson or fermion with $\ell,m$ with the wavefunction $\langle r | \ell,m\rangle$.

Comment: But $\langle r_1 | \otimes \langle r_2 | \ell,m\rangle$ makes no sense physically. So to understand the inversion parity of a product state of two elementary states, with definite inversion parity, I guess I need to understand how to think of inversion-parity in a basis-independent way, without the crutch of wavefunctions. Does the state |\ell,m\rangle have definite inversion-parity irrespective of whether it is an eigenstate of $L^2,L_z$ of a single entity or a direct sum of $L_i^2,L_{iz}$ of an arbitrary number of entities....

Comment: I should clarify that by inversion-parity I mean the sign change when $x\rightarrow-x,y\rightarrow-y,z\rightarrow-z$, as opposed to what is called reflection-parity in condensed matter and just parity in high energy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)) which is the sign change on flipping one spatial coordinate. Edited the original question to disambiguate this. Leaving this comment here to put earlier comments in context.

Comment: Your question has drifted to something completely different. Why don't you edit/reconfigure it with a fresh mind to articulate what you are *really* asking? At this point, the title is thoroughgoingly misleading...